# Is there a wordpress function that allows a page to display all posts from some specific category?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We have a wordpress function to display all the posts like-

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {

        the_post(); ?>

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php }
}
?>
```

Is there any function in wordpress that will displays only the posts from some specific category?

like -

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {

        the_post(); ?>

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> //from Category = X

    <?php }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply fetch it with the function :

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=x' ); ?>
```

where "x" is your category ID

This function offert multiple advantages as you can filter and order the result

---

Get category 3 posts from 2004

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=3&year=2004' ); ?>
```

Get category 1 posts from 2004 and order by date ASCENDING.

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=1'.'&year=2004&orderby=date&order=asc'); ?>
```

---

Want to retrieve the actual category ? Simply use :

```
<?php 

$catId = get_cat_ID('MYCATEGORY'); //get current category id

query_posts( 'cat='.$catId ); // query the posts

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<h1>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```